# How Apple.com set Apple Touch Icon?

Tags: ios, safari, icon

Apple Touch Icon is a icon used in Safari 8 favourite new page on OS X,or web clip in Home screen on iOS.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html
there is two way to set it,one is using rel="shortcut icon",another is using rel="apple-touch-icon" like http://apple.stackexchange.com do.So I can find icon URL http://cdn.sstatic.net/apple/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=2a2c3caaec7f
However apple.com doesn't use those two method.How can I find apple.com's apple touch icon URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Safari use mobile UA to get mobile HTML to get mobile Apple Touch Icon to set Desktop Safari favorite bar.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just http://www.apple.com/apple-touch-icon.png?

From the [iOS Developer Library article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) you pointed to above...

> To specify an icon for the entire website (every page on the website), place an icon file in PNG format in the root document folder called apple-touch-icon.png

Comment: But I add to my website www.cuthead.tk/apple-touch-icon.png,add www.cuthead.tk to my favourite,why I still not see the icon show out?

Comment: It works for me when I try to create a bookmark (favorite is the term used by Internet Explorer) or web clip in iOS 8 Safari on an iPhone 5S.